# url is scraped but still og tags are not updating on facebook page post

Tags: debugging, curl, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I published a post on page.Published post has correct og:tags but when I am updating my tags these tags are not showing changed on my FB page.

I have tried debug [tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and curl both. Debugger tool is showing changed values similarly curl's response is showing scraped response with time but in both the situation my page is not showing changed values.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Posts don’t get updated automatically, just because you change the OG meta tags later.

Take a second to think about it - if I made you share a funny kittykat picture today, and tomorrow switched out thumbnail and description for “buy ch3ap v1agr4 here” ... that could hardly be in your interest as a Facebook user.

Users/pages will have to explicitly ask Facebook to update the data for existing posts. There is an option for that in the UI, the dropdown menu for the individual post has a “refresh share attachment” entry.